# "Quota exceeded (122)" error on ec2 instance with EFS and docker containers

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm, amazon-efs

Today I started to see the following error on one of my sites:

> NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning: fopen(/www/wordpress/wp-content/languages/plugins/wordpress-seo-es_ES.mo): failed to open stream: "Quota exceeded" in /www/wordpress/wp-includes/pomo/streams.php on line 148

It's not "disk quota exceeded" which is what I mostly find when searching for the error, its just "quota exceeded".

The site runs on a container with nginx + php-fpm on an aws ec2 instance with plenty of available space, and wordpress contents are on an EFS shared filesystem. The error occurs with many files, not just the one on the error (but its the one that most appears on the logs).

I really have no idea to which quota is referring to. Any hints are very appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT (05/05/2020):**

The error seems to not be specifically related to php-fpm, I started another service and the nginx container failed to start with the same error:

```
** [php-fpm] Starting php-fpm 7.0.33 nginx: [emerg] open() "/www/wordpress/.nginx_conf" failed (122: Quota exceeded) in
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:28
** [nginx] Starting nginx 1.17.6 nginx: [emerg] open() "/www/wordpress/.nginx_conf" failed (122: Quota exceeded) in
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:28 [04-May-2020 20:01:42] ERROR: failed
to open error_log (/www/logs/php-fpm/php-fpm.log): Quota exceeded
(122) [04-May-2020 20:01:42] ERROR: failed to post process the
configuration [04-May-2020 20:01:42] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
** [php-fpm] Starting php-fpm  [04-May-2020 20:01:42] ERROR: failed to open error_log (/www/logs/php-fpm/php-fpm.log): Quota exceeded (122)
[04-May-2020 20:01:42] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[04-May-2020 20:01:42] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

and is not only with that container, I have found that error on all containers running on that machine, so it seems to be an o.s. error. I still cannot find what that "Quota exceeded (122)" error is.

Comment: I am also running into this. "Quota exceeded" not "Disk quota exceeded" as you pointed out. We have been suspecting AWS API requests are the quotas it's referring to, but after fixing what we thought was the source of that, it has occurred again. Restarting the ECS instances we're running on resets it. The theory is that creates a new API key that resets the limit. AWS reporting on API usage is not great, so I think the next step is to open a ticket with them and see if they can give more information that the cryptic 2 word error (if it's even from them).

Comment: I should also mention, we're not running wordpress or any PHP app, it's appearing in a Go background worker service.